How to make `refetchQueries` trigger regardless of whether data is cached or not?
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import api from "./Api";

export const useUploadProduct = () => {
  const qc = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (newProduct) => {
      const res = await api.post("/products", newProduct);
      return res.data;
    },

    onSuccess: () => {
      qc.refetchQueries(["products"]);
    },
  });
};

I have two web pages: one that displays all products and another that allows you to upload a new product.
Usually, refetchQueries are triggered automatically when I add a new product, but this only happens if the products were cached previously (meaning the products page was visited before the upload page).
However, if I upload a new product without first visiting the ‘All Products’ page (meaning no data is cached), refetchQueries does not trigger.

My question is: How can I fetch all products after uploading a new product, regardless of whether [“products”] were fetched before or not?


Are you using the products result in the Upload product page? If not, I think it is okay if the refetch fails. Since you're gonna fetch again when you visit the All products page anyway.

I use the ["products"] result in the All products page only, so i want prefetch the data before opening the page.

Then check if the query is cached, and it is cached, just refetch, otherwise call the original query via calling the origina useQuery.
